# measure of generic reals in forcing extensions

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

It is well-known that if $V[G]$ is a generic extension by adding a Cohen real, then 
the set $\{r \in V[G]: r$ is Cohen generic over $V\}$ has measure zero.

On the other hand, if $V[G]$ is a generic extension by adding a random real, then 
the set $\{r \in V[G]: r$ is random over $V\}$ has outer measure one.

> **Question.** I am wondering what is know about other generic reals? Are there any cases  where the answer for them is not known?

Please provide references or proofs for each case.

Comment: Since a Mathias real (viewed as a subset of $\omega$) has asymptotic density $0$, the set of Mathias reals in any forcing extension will have measure $0$. The same trivial observation will handle some other cases of your question, but I'll be interested to see nontrivial information.

Comment: Another observation: If $g$ is a Sacks real over $V$, then the set of Sacks reals in $V[g]$ cannot have measure $0$. This is because *every* real in $S = \mathbb R^{V[g]} \setminus \mathbb R^V$ is a Sacks real, so if $S$ were null then $S \cup (S+g)$ would be too; however, $S \cup (S+g) = \mathbb R^{V[g]}$. Because $S$ is closed under rational translations, its being non-null implies it has full outer measure. My guess would be that $\mathbb R^V$ is null in $V[g]$, but I'm not sure right now.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I think that both $S$ and its complement should have full outer measure. The reason is that if $\mathbb R^V$ were null in $V[g]$, then iterating the Sacks forcing (in the usual way -- length $\omega_2$, countable supports) would produce a model where, e.g., every non-measurable set has size $\aleph_2$. This doesn't happen, so adding a Sacks real can't make the ground model reals null. So I guess this shows that after adding a Sacks real, the set of Sacks reals is non-measurable with full outer measure.

Comment: Let $I$ be a $\sigma$-ideal on the reals and suppose that there is $X\in I$ and a Lebesgue null set $Y$ such that $X\cup Y$ is a partition of the reals (such as the case when $I$ is the meager ideal), then every $\mathbb{P}_I$ generic real must be in $Y$, hence the set of $\mathbb{P}_I$-generic reals has measure zero. My guess is that the above condition should be equivalent to "the set of $\mathbb{P}_I$-generics is null", but I haven't thought about this carefully.

Comment: If $r$ is random, then in $L[r]$, the set of random reals is not measureable

Comment: (cont) I'm no longer sure that the converse is true in general, though it should work in the following case: if $\mathbb{P}_I$ has the Sacks property then every null set in the generic extension is contained in a Borel null set $X\in V$. If the set of $\mathbb{P}_I$-generic reals is null, then it's contained in such an $X$. If in addition $\mathbb R \setminus X \in I$, then $X\cup (\mathbb R \setminus X)$ is the desired partition.

Comment: You may find some  more examples in the book Set Theory: On the Structure of the Real Line by Tomek Bartoszynski and Haim Judah

Comment: Sounds like there might be also a general theorem about this in the form of an ideal-based forcing. Maybe try and find it in Zapletal's book.